# $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{6}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})]$ = ?.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

In order to find the value I took $F =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

So,$F(\sqrt{6}) = \{a + b\sqrt{6} | a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\}$

So expanding the elements $a$ and $b$ as elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$,
$= (a_{1} + b_{1}\sqrt{2}) +(a_{2}+b_{2}\sqrt{2})\sqrt{6}$

Solving a bit more gives me

$a_{1} + b_{1}\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}(a_{2}\sqrt{2} + 2b_{2})$.

Now are the basis elements $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Now how do I choose the basis elements in order to find the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{6})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ ?

Any help is great!

Comment: If you show the dimension is at most $2$ and that it is not $1$ then it must be $2$.

Comment: Why the dimension can be atmost $2$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)(\sqrt 6)=\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)(\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3) (\sqrt 2)$

Comment: So you need to find if $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ or not. If it does then $\sqrt{2} = a+b \sqrt{3}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, and hence $2 = (a+b \sqrt{3})^2$ ...

Comment: And you don't know a priori that the elements of $F(\sqrt{6})$ can be written uniquely as $a + b\sqrt{6}, a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (it depends if $\sqrt{6} \in F$ or not)